# UIALogger translate from java script to swift

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, unit-testing, ios-ui-automation

Does anyone know the equivalent of this java script line in Swift?
I am trying to log a message or send a message to Xcode console once a UI automated test has passed or failed individual sections

Java Script
UIALogger.logMessage("...");

Swift?

on Xcode 7